# Dependency not working with my application

Tags: python, pip, dependencies

I have a bash script which installs some packages then runs a Python application.

This is one of the commands it executes:

```
python -m pip install -e git+ssh://git@github.mycompany.com/dev/python-config.git@release/1.0-dev#egg=python-config
```

My Python appplication fails with this error:

```
ImportError: No module named config.token_manager
```

`config.token_manager` is in my python-config application.

I tried a pip freeze and could see that there is no `python-config`. Im not really sure where to go from here. Does anybody have any advice?

**Additional Info**

```
Mon Mar  4 20:45:30 UTC 2019 -- running test setup.py
running develop
running egg_info
creating sdk_config.egg-info
writing requirements to sdk_config.egg-info/requires.txt
writing sdk_config.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to sdk_config.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to sdk_config.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'sdk_config.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'sdk_config.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'sdk_config.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sdk-config.egg-link (link to .)
Removing sdk-config 1.0-dev from easy-install.pth file
Adding sdk-config 1.0.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /opt/sdk_python_config/virtualenv
Processing dependencies for ibm-cos-sdk-config==1.0.0
```

Comment: What is the output from running that `pip` command? Does it contain any errors?

Comment: I don't see any errors.

Comment: Could you paste the complete error trace here, including the output of `python -m pip `

Comment: @runnerpaul: You need to show *exactly* how the `python -m pip` command is being executed. As you show it, the exit status `$?` isn't being used, so apparently the bash script doesn't notice if `pip` failed? You don't necessarily need to show the whole bash script, but at least enough to show anything that might affect the execution of `python`. And I'm *certain* that there is output being generated by `pip`: find that output, as it's almost certainly very relevant.

Comment: I added some more info. Is that what you're after? The version I'm interested in is `1.0-dev`. It gets installed by my bash script. `1.0.0` seems to happen after. I think it's doen by setup.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that I had the same name specified in the setup.py for both my aplication and the dependency. Whan I changed one the application worked.